# Haskell: how to detect "lazy memory leaks"

Tags: haskell, optimization, memory-leaks, lazy-evaluation

After few hours of debugging, I realized that a very simple toy example was not efficient due to a missing `!` in an expression `return $ 1 + x` (thanks duplode!... but how come ghc does not optimize that??). I also realized it because I was comparing it with a Python code that was quicker, but I won't always write Python code to benchmark my code...

So here is my question: is there a way to automatically detect these "lazy memory leaks", that slow down a program for no real reason? I'm still pretty bad to optimize Haskell code, and forgetting a `!` is quite likely, even when you're experienced I guess.

I'm aware of:

- the `+RTS -s`, but I'm not sure how to interpret it: seeing `79MB` of memory for a simple program seems huge to me for example, but maybe it's not as it's what takes my current program... and for bigger programs it's impossible to just detect "lazy leaks" that way I guess as I have no idea of the amount of memory my program should take.
- the `cabal v2-run --enable-profiling mysatsolvers -- +RTS -p` command, but it seems that enabling the profiler kills some optimisations done by GHC, and therefore it's hard to use these values for a real benchmark. And still, it's not clear to me how to find leaks from that output anyway.

Could you for example explain to me how I could find the "lazy leaks" in a toy program like this one?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where

--- It depends on the transformers, containers, and base packages.
--- Optimisation seems to be important or the NoLog case will be way to long.
--- $ ghc -O Main.hs

import qualified Data.Map.Strict as MapStrict
import Data.Functor.Identity

import qualified Control.Monad as CM
import qualified Control.Monad.State.Strict as State
import qualified Data.Time as Time

-- Create a class that allows me to use the function "myTell"
-- that adds a number in the writer (either the LogEntry
-- or StupidLogEntry one)
class Monad m => LogFunctionCalls m where
  myTell :: String -> Int -> m ()

---------- Logging disabled ----------
--- (No logging at all gives the same time so I don't put here)
newtype NoLog a = NoLog { unNoLog :: a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad) via Identity

instance LogFunctionCalls NoLog where
  myTell _ _ = pure ()

---------- Logging with Map ----------
-- When logging, associate a number to each name.
newtype LogEntryMap = LogEntryMap (MapStrict.Map String Int)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance LogFunctionCalls (State.State LogEntryMap) where
  myTell namefunction n = State.modify' $
    \(LogEntryMap m) ->
      LogEntryMap $ MapStrict.insertWith (+) namefunction n m

---------- Logging with Int ----------
-- Don't use any Map to avoid inefficiency of Map
newtype LogEntryInt = LogEntryInt Int
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance LogFunctionCalls (State.State LogEntryInt) where
  myTell namefunction n = State.modify' $
    \(LogEntryInt m) -> LogEntryInt $! m + n

---------- Function to compute ----------
countNumberCalls :: (LogFunctionCalls m) => Int -> m Int
countNumberCalls 0 = return 0
countNumberCalls n = do
  myTell "countNumberCalls" 1
  x <- countNumberCalls $! n - 1
  return $ 1 + x

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let www = 15000000
  putStrLn $ "Let's start!"
  --- Logging disabled
  t0 <- Time.getCurrentTime
  let n = unNoLog $ countNumberCalls www
  putStrLn $ "Logging disabled: " ++ (show n)
  t1 <- Time.getCurrentTime
  print (Time.diffUTCTime t1 t0)
  -- Logging with Map
  let (n, LogEntryMap log) = State.runState (countNumberCalls www) (LogEntryMap MapStrict.empty)
  putStrLn $ "Logging with Map: " ++ (show n)
  putStrLn $ (show $ log)
  t2 <- Time.getCurrentTime
  print (Time.diffUTCTime t2 t1)
  -- Logging with Int
  let (n, LogEntryInt log) = State.runState (countNumberCalls www) (LogEntryInt 0)
  putStrLn $ "Logging with Int: " ++ (show n)
  putStrLn $ (show $ log)
  t3 <- Time.getCurrentTime
  print (Time.diffUTCTime t3 t2)
```

Comment: Please consider opening a GHC ticket with your case here. It might be there's a reason the demand analyzer can't be improved here but who knows. GHC HQ would probably appreciate this self-contained example

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The main method for detecting memory leaks is heap profiling.  Specifically, you're looking for unexpected growth in the amount of *resident* (mostly heap) memory, either the maximum residency in the `+RTS -s` statistics output, or -- more reliably -- a characteristic "pyramid" shape over time in heap profile output generated with the `+RTS -h<x>` flags and the `hp2ps` tool.

If I run your toy program with `+RTS -s`, I see:

```
   3,281,896,520 bytes allocated in the heap
   3,383,195,568 bytes copied during GC
     599,346,304 bytes maximum residency (17 sample(s))
       5,706,584 bytes maximum slop
             571 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

The first line can generally be ignored.  Haskell programs typically allocate a roughly constant amount of memory per second of runtime, and this allocation rate is either nearly zero (for certain, unusual programs), or 0.5-2.0 gigabytes per second.  This program ran for 4 seconds and allocated 3.8 gigabytes, and that's not unusual.

The bytes copied during GC and maximum residency are concerning, though.  Assuming you have a program that you expect to run in constant space (i.e., there's no ever-growing data structure whose entire contents are needed), a correctly functioning Haskell program will generally not need to copy much data during garbage collection and will tend to have a maximum residency that's a small fraction of the total bytes allocated (e.g., 100 kilobytes rather than half a gigabyte), and this won't grow substantially with the number of "iterations" of whatever it is you're testing.

You can generate a quick heap profile over time without turning on formal profiling.  If you compile with the GHC flag `-rtsopts`, you can use:

```
./Toy +RTS -hT
```

and then display the result graphically using the `hp2ps` tool:

```
hp2ps -c -e8in Toy.hp
evince Toy.ps &
```

This sort of pyramid pattern is a red flag:

[image]

Note that rapid linear increase in heap to the tune of hundreds of megabytes per second followed by a rapid linear collapse.  This is the pattern you see when a huge lazy data structure is being needlessly built up before the entire computation is forced all at once.  You see two pyramids here because both your second and third tests are exhibiting memory leaks.

As an aside, the x-axis is in "MUT seconds" (seconds the "mutator" is running, which excludes garbage collection), so that's why this is less than the actual 4 second runtime.  That's actually another red flag.  A Haskell program that's spending half its time garbage collecting probably isn't running correctly.

To get more detail on what's causing this heap pyramid, you'll need to compile with profiling enabled.  Profiling may cause a program to run somewhat slower but doesn't normally change which optimizations are in place.  However, the flag `-fprof-auto` (and related flags) which automatically insert cost centers have the potential of causing big performance changes (by interfering with inlining, etc.).  Unfortunately, the cabal `--enable-profiling` flag turns on profiling (compiler flag `-prof`) **and** the flag `-fprof-auto-top` which automatically generates cost centers for top-level functions, so for your toy example, that substantially changes the behavior of your first test case (increasing the runtime from 0.4 seconds to 5 seconds, even with no `+RTS` flags).  That may be the problem you're seeing with profiling affecting your results.  You don't need any cost centers for several additional kinds of heap profiles, so you can add the cabal flag `--profiling-detail=none` to shut that off, and then your profiled program should run with timing a little slower but generally similar performance to the unprofiled version.

I don't use Cabal, but compiling with the following (which should be the equivalent of `--enable-profiling --profiling-detail=none`):

```
ghc -O2 -rtsopts -prof Toy.hs    # no -fprof-auto...
```

I can run your program with profiling by data type:

```
./Toy +RTS -hy
```

If I look at the heap profile graph:

[image]

this attributes most of the heap to the `Int` type -- this narrows my problem down to a bunch of unevaluated lazy `Int` calculations, which might point me in the right direction.

If I'm really having trouble narrowing things down and am feeling like a technical deep-dive, I can also run a heap profile by closure (flag `-hd`).  This tells me that the culprits are `Main.sat_s7mQ` and `Main.sat_s7kP` for the two pyramids respectively.  This looks very mysterious, but they're the names of functions in the "STG", a low-level intermediate representation of my program generated by the compiler.

If I recompile with the same flags but add `-fforce-recomp -ddump-stg -dsuppress-all`:

```
ghc -O2 -rtsopts -prof -fforce-recomp -ddump-stg -dsuppress-all Toy.hs
```

this will dump the STG that contains the definitions of these two functions.  (The generated identifiers can differ with small changes to code and/or compiler flags, so it's best to recompile with the STG dumped and then re-profile that executable, to make sure the identifiers match.)

If I search the STG for the first culprit, I find the definition:

```
sat_s7mQ =
    CCCS \u []
        case ww2_s7mL of {
          I# y_s7mO ->
              case +# [1# y_s7mO] of sat_s7mP {
                __DEFAULT -> I# [sat_s7mP];
              };
        };
```

Yes, this is all very technical, but this is STG-speak for the expression `1 + y`, which would help me zero in on the culprit.

If you don't speak STG, you can try introducing some cost centers.  For example, I tried profiling *only* your second test case with `-fprof-auto` (Cabal flag `--profiling-detail=all-functions`).  The profile output in `Toy.prof` isn't *that* useful for memory leaks because it deals with total allocation instead of active (i.e., resident and not garbage collected) allocations over time, but you can create a heap profile by cost center by running:

```
./Toy +RTS -hc
```

In this case, it attributes everything to a single cost center, namely `(315)countNumberCalls`.  The "315" is the cost center number which you can look up in the `Toy.prof` input to find the exact source code lines, if it's not clear from the name.  Anyway, this at least helps narrow down the problem to `countNumberCalls`.

For more complicated functions, you can sometimes narrow down the problem further by manually specifying cost centers, like so:

```
countNumberCalls :: (LogFunctionCalls m) => Int -> m Int
countNumberCalls 0 = return 0
countNumberCalls n = do
  {-# SCC "mytell_call" #-} myTell "countNumberCalls" 1
  x <- {-# SCC "recursive_call" #-} countNumberCalls $! n - 1
  {-# SCC "return_statment" #-} return $ {-# SCC "one_plus_x" #-} 1 + x
```

This actually attributes everything to "recursive_call", so it's not that helpful.

It's not wrong, though.  You actually have two memory leaks here -- the `x <- countNumberCalls $! n - 1` leaks heap because `x` isn't forced, and the `1 + x` leaks stack.  You could enable the `BangPatterns` extension and write:

```
!x <- countNumebrCalls $1 n - 1
```

and that would actually remove one of the memory leaks, speeding up the second case from 2.5 seconds to 1.0 seconds and dropping the maximum residency from 460 megs to 95 megs (and the bytes copied during GC from 1.5 Gigs to 73 kilobytes!).  However, a heap profile would show linear growing stack accounting for pretty much all of that resident memory.  Because stack isn't as well-tracked as heap, that would be more difficult to track down.

Some additional notes:

Even though the `+RTS -h<x>` flags are primarily for heap profiling (and are discussed as "heap profiling" options in the GHC documentation), they can technically report on other uses of resident
memory besides heap including per-thread state, which includes thread state objects and stack.  By default, when running a profiled binary (compiled with `-prof`), the `+RTS -h<x>` flags do *not* report on per-thread state including stack, but you can add the [`-xt` flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#rts-flag--xt) to add it, as in `+RTS -hc -xt`.  Due to a probable unintentional oversight, on a non-profiled binary, the `+RTS -hT` flag (the only `-h<x>` flag available) includes stack even without the `-xt` flag.  Due to a compiler [bug](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/15086), the `-hT` flag doesn't work on profiled binaries for GHC 8.6.x and earlier, but it does work on GHC 8.8.x, and for that version, `+RTS -hT` includes stack on non-profiled binaries but excludes it on profiled binaries unless you also specify `-xt`.  That's why in the examples above, "Stack" only shows up when running a heap profile on a non-profiled binary.  You can add the `-xt` flag to see it for all the other heap profiles.  Note that this "STACK" is actual stack use, rather than objects on the heap that are some how affiliated with the stack.

Black holes are primarily a mechanism for supporting concurrency.  When a thread starts evaluating a thunk, it "blackholes" it (i.e., marks it as a black hole), so that if another thread comes along and wants to evaluate the same thunk, it waits on the evaluation instead of trying to re-evaluate it in parallel (which would duplicate the effort of the running thread).  It's also used in the non-threaded runtime, partly because it can detect infinite loops (if a thread encounters its own black hole), but also for some more important reasons that I can't remember.  For `-hT`, `-hd`, and `-hy` heap profiling, heap objects that have been blackholed like this will be marked as "BLACKHOLE".  The limited sampling rate in the profiles above can make it a little unclear, but what's happening in your program is that a large series of `Int` thunks are being built in a chain, and when the value is finally forced, they are turned into a long chain of `BLACKHOLE`s, each of which represents a computation that's been initiated and is waiting on the next computation in the chain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's super useful and complete! I just have a few questions, like for example, what is the meaning of "blackhole" in the diagrams (in my case blackholes are smaller than thunk, while in your case thunk are bigger don't know why)? And the "stack" in the first picture refers to element in the heap that point to the stack or it's something else? (I'm a bit lost because I though we were doing heap profiling)

Comment: I added some notes at the end about "BLACKHOLE" and "STACK".  I don't know why your blackhole use is different than mine.  It could be differences in GHC version, or it could be chance -- profiling is done by sampling, and the timing of the samples can change the apparent pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the sampling rate? Obviously that would make the program running slower but sampling accuracy would increase. In perfect world, one could turn on and off the high frequency sampling with e.g. signals being sent to the program.

Comment: Yes, the heap profile sample rate is set by the `+RTS -i<xx>` option which gives the samples per second.  It defaults to `+RTS -i0.01`.  I'm not aware of any way of changing it in a running program, though.

Comment: `3,281,896,520 bytes allocated in the heap`. Please explain this for readers as to **why** this line should be ignored. If it is _actually_ allocated, then it is a problem? And in that case, why should one look at the other figures which are usually lower?

Answer (score 6):

You ask

> `return $ 1 + x` [...] but how come ghc does not optimize that??

The answer is that strict evaluation and lazy evaluation have subtly different semantics, so having GHC optimise it might break your program.

The difference lies in the treatment of undefined values. Any attempt to evaluate an `undefined` throws an exception. In GHCi:

```
Prelude> undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:1:1 in interactive:Ghci1
```

If I have an expression that contains an undefined then the same thing happens:

```
Prelude> 2 + undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined [...]
```

However if the evaluation never gets to the undefined then everything is fine:

```
Prelude> True || undefined
True
```

Haskell uses "non-strict semantics" and "lazy evaluation". Technically the non-strict semantics are part of the definition of Haskell and lazy evaluation is the implementation mechanism in GHC, but you can think of them as synonyms. When you define a variable the value is not computed immediately, so if you never use the variable then you have no problem:

```
Prelude> let b = undefined
Prelude> b
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

The `let` works fine, but evaluating the variable it defines throws an exception.

Now consider your towering stack of unevaluated `1+` calls. GHC has no way of knowing in advance whether you are ever going to use the result (see below), and it also has no way of knowing whether or not there is an exception lurking in there somewhere. As a programmer you might know that there is an exception and carefully not look at the result, relying on the non-strict semantics of Haskell. If GHC prematurely evaluates and gets an exception your program will fail when it should not have.

Actually the GHC compiler includes a piece of optimisation called the [Demand Analyser](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/demand) (it used to be called the Strictness Analyser) which looks for opportunities to optimise in exactly the way you want. However it has limits because it can only optimise computations when it can *prove* that the result is going to be evaluated.

Another wrinkle here is that you have used the [State monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2). This actually comes in two variants; Lazy and Strict. The Strict variant forces the state when it gets written, but the Lazy variant (the default) doesn't.

Comment: I understand yes, but here it does not seem very hard to see that the state will actually be displayed (it's printed, and the function can't be much simpler), and that it can't produce errors when the integer is bigger than 0. I do understand that the monad can be an issue tough, but given the fact that I'm using it with a strict state monad... I'd say it's still doable. But anyway, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @tobiasBora Ahh, sorry, I missed the "Strict" in your import. I know this stuff is a pain because I once spent a week tracking down this exact issue in a program I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific class of space leaks that can be detected because they use excessive amounts of stack when they unwind the excessive heap usage. The [following website](https://github.com/ndmitchell/spaceleak) lists the specific approaches, along with lots of case studies, but roughly:

- Compile and run with a limited size stack, using `+RTS -K10K` to limit the stack to 10Kb.
- Examine the code that breaks the stack limit, using `+RTS -xc` to get stack traces.

It's not a perfect approach since sometimes you have memory leaks without excessive stack usage, and sometimes you have excessive stack usage without memory leaks, but the correspondence is pretty good and the tooling can be deployed on CI to stop introducing new leaks.